# How to use a .dmg file

Tags: install, dmg

I'm trying to use a .dmg file. I have it downloaded and everything but whenever I try to open it, it doesn't do anything. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The image file is a box. What happens when you open it depends on who filled the box. If you have an empty box, maybe nothing happening is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Double-clicking a .dmg "mounts" it (which kind of is tech slang for "make its content available), and usually it should then show up in the side bar of a Finder window. If it doesn't, type <kbd>Shift-Cmd-G</kbd> and enter `/Volumes` followed by <kbd>Return</kbd> to see a list of all mounted volumes. One of them should be your .dmg file.